# Make a histogram without frequency as an axis in R?

Tags: r

I'm doing a project which is analyzing the success of an athlete with respect to height and country of origin. Is it possible to create a histogram in R with the height as x axis separated into bins and the y axis representing the total number of medals won in that specific bin?

Comment: Need a sample dataset. See: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: You are describing a bar chart, not a histogram.

Answer (score 0):

To MrFlick's point, you are really trying to create a bar chart based on bins.

My answer below is using the "Discoveries" data set as an example of how I would do this, creating a bar chart for the number of significant discoveries every 10 years, when the data is given to us by year:

```
library(datasets)
library(ggplot2)

# number of discoveries per year from 1860-1959
data(discoveries) 

# make data frame and add a column for the year
test <- data.frame(discoveries, year = c(1860:1959)) 

#set size of bin
bin_size = 10

#create bin field based on test$year and test$bin_size
test$year_bins <- findInterval(test$year, seq(if(round(min(test$year)) == min(test$year)) {
                                            min(test$year)
                                            } else {
                                            (round(min(test$year)/bin_size)-1)*bin_size
                                          },
                                          if(round(max(test$year)) == max(test$year)) {
                                            max(test$year)
                                          } else {
                                            (round(max(test$year)/bin_size)+1)*bin_size
                                          },
                                      bin_size))

#aggregate total discoveries by bin number
test2 <- aggregate(discoveries ~ year_bins, data = test, FUN = sum)

#create a bar chart for test3
ggplot(data= test2, aes(x=year_bins, y=discoveries)) +
 geom_bar(colour="black", stat = "identity") +
 guides(fill = FALSE) +
 scale_x_continuous(breaks = 1:max(test2$year_bins))
```